# How to prevent generation of duplicate id fields in a foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net-core, mvvm, .net-core, razor-pages

What is the procedure for generating unique element id's when iterating through a for each loop?

**INPUT**

```
@foreach (var x in Model.Class.Where(h => h.ID == 0))
{
  <form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@x.Field">
  </form>
}
```

Currently the `asp-for` tag will automatically generate an id from the model but it will create the same id for every element that is rendered within the loop.

**OUTPUT**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-val="true" id="x_Field" name="x_Field" checked="checked" value="true">
```

**WITHOUT ASP-FOR**

Or do I have to hardcore the html instead of using `asp-for` for iterating like this?

```
<input id="x[@x.Id].Field" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retain the same value for the `name` attribute but have different values for the `id` attribute, you can pass an explicit value which will override the tag helper's generated value based on the property name:

```
@foreach (var x in Model.Class.Where(h => h.ID == 0))
{
  <form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@x.Field" id="@($"custom{x.ID}")">
  </form>
}
```